# Errata on "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" book or bad memory understanding?

Tags: objective-c

In the book "Learn Objective-C on the Mac' you can find the following code which I think is an errata:

---

"Here's another attempt at writing setEngine:

```
- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine  
{  
      [engine release];  
      engine = [newEngine retain];  
}
```

... ponder this case:

```
Engine *engine = [Engine new]; // count: 1  
Car *car1 = [Car new];  
Car *car2 = [Car new]; 

[car1 setEngine: engine]; // count: 2 
[engine release]; // count 1 

[car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; //Ops...
```

Why is this a problem? Here's what's happening. [car engine] returns a pointer to engine which has a retain count of 1. The first line of setEngine is [engine release], which makes the retain count 0, an the object gets deallocated...."

---

However, after reading this paragraph on page 166. I wonder what the internal engine reference in car2 has to do with engine in car1. They are two different references and by te time "[car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]]" is invoke, the engine in car2 hasn't been initialized and keeps no relation to the retained engine the author talks about. So "[engine release]" won't decrease te counter to 0 of car1 engine.
See my point? Is it an errata or am I terrible wrong?

((I would like to discuss this particular code, not the right way of implementing a setter))

Comment: I also think that if you replace "Car *car2=[Car new]" with "Car *car2=car1" the whole thing makes sense.

Comment: It would be a problem if there were a `[car2 setEngine:engine]` before the last instruction. Otherwise, it’s okay (correctly implementing setter methods notwithstanding).

Comment: looks like a typo. [car1 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; would also make the example work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What class is setEngine: in?  I'm assuming it's in Car.  And that Car has an instance variable of type Engine* called engine.  Which is NOT the same Engine* pointer as in the second code fragment (which should be a controller class with it's own instance variables).

First, engine IS initialized.  `[Engine new]` is the same (for all practical purposes) as `[[Engine alloc] init]`.

So you've got two Car objects, and 1 Engine object.  You set the engine instance variable in car1 to point to the engine object.  Then release the original pointer.  Fine.  Then you assign it to car2 as well.  If car2 had a different engine, it gets released and the new one assigned.  If it didn't have an engine assigned, the release message gets sent to nil (which is fine), and it gets assigned as well.

It's all fine.

PS - while Objective-C has the `new` construct, it's generally a bad idea to use it because it obscures the two-stage creation pattern that is the norm for Apple frameworks.  Use alloc & init.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I thought. So the book is wrong in saying the counter goes to 0 on line  [car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]];

Comment: Ah, and Sorry.  You were right in all assumptions about the Car object.

Comment: Yes, I think the book is probably wrong.  The only way the release can cause the retain count on the single Engine object to go to zero is if that instance of Car (car2) was already pointing to the Engine object.  And in that case, the retain count couldn't be 1, because both car1 and car2 would have the same pointer.

Comment: Yep, I reported an errata. Let's see what they say. the book would be accurate if car2 is set to: Car *car2 = car1 instead to a new object.

Comment: True, but then you only have one Car object, which is not equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

The setter isn't right. It might be:

```
- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine  
{
  if(newEngine != engine)
  {
   [engine release];  
   engine = [newEngine retain]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said, im not interested in discussing the right way to implement a setter. I already know that. What I want is to find out why the  author of the book says that about the retain count.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the setter.  Checking to see if it's already the same object is an nice optimization, but not necessary.

Comment: Or just retain `newEngine` prior to releasing `engine`.

Comment: The one in the original post.  The one in the second answer works as well, but it's just a slight optimization.

Comment: The original setter is also flawled. Imagine this:

[car1 setEngine: engine]; 
[engine release];  
[car1 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; //Ops...

In the second "setEngine", engine counter would be 0 and it might be dealocaled, the next line you try to retain an -possible- already dealocated object.