# What is retain count in this chunk of code?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

From the book "Learn Objective-C on the mac (second edition)".
Why `retain count` is 2 but not 1 in the following chunk of code:-

```
- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine
{
   [engine release];
   engine = [newEngine retain];
   // More BAD CODE: do not steal. Fixed version below.
}  // setEngine

some_function 
{
   Engine *engine = [Engine new]; // count: 1

   Car *car1 = [Car new];
   Car *car2 = [Car new];

   [car1 setEngine: engine];   // count: 2 But why? 1-1=0 (due to [engine release]  
                              // in -(void) SetEngine.    
                              // and after engine=[newEngine retain] retain count is 1.

   [engine release]; // count 1 
   [car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; // oops!

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: People who actually _use_ the retain count are almost invariably doing the wrong thing :-)

Comment: [engine release] call for previous setted engine. Use Arc, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please consider switching to ARC. There's really no reason in ordinary programming to need to use MRC.

Second, you're getting your scopes mixed up. Remember that there are really five `Engine*` pointers in this code but only one `Engine` object.

Within `some_function`:

1. `engine`, the local variable
2. `car1.engine`
3. `car2.engine`

Within the `setEngine:` method:

1. `engine`, the ivar
2. `newEngine`, the parameter

Here's what's happening in the code:

1. `engine = [Engine new];` Retains the engine, retain count = 1
2. `[car1 setEngine:engine];`

   - `[engine release];` Releases the car's engine ivar, which is probably set to `nil`, and does nothing. retain count = 1
   - `engine = [newEngine retain];` Retains the engine, retain count = 2
3. `[engine release];` Releases the engine, retain count = 1
4. `car2 setEngine:engine];`

   - `[engine release];` Releases the car's engine ivar, which is probably set to `nil`, and does nothing. retain count = 1
   - `engine = [newEngine retain];` Retains the engine, retain count = 2

Now, please do yourself a favor and let the compiler handle reference counting for you.

Comment: I know about ARC. I only try to understand memory management.
[engine release]; Releases the car's engine ivar, which is probably set to nil, and does nothing. retain count = 1 - why retain count to 1, if we release it? So -1 may be?? Suppose, it is impossible. 
And small adition, I've found link to my question after it had been asked: "Errata on “Learn Objective-C on the Mac” book or bad memory understanding?" - so may be error in this book??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374475/errata-on-learn-objective-c-on-the-mac-book-or-bad-memory-understanding

Comment: @user2553675 It's not an error. The `engine` pointer in the `setEngine` method is a different pointer than the `engine` pointer in `some_function`. Different scope, different pointer. You should read more about how function/method calls work, since that's where your confusion is. You're understanding the concept of reference counting just fine.

Comment: Perhaps I've understood. In method setEngine not variable engine from the main scop being released, but instance var in Car class.
And in [car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; is passed Car's engine instance var which now is nil. Thank you.

Comment: @user2553675 You got it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check my comments

```
- (void) setEngine: (Engine *) newEngine
{
   // setEngine: is method defined inside Car.
   // so engine reference is retained by Car
   // and it should be released when Car is released 
   // ie. in car dealloc method
   [engine release];
   engine = [newEngine retain];
   // More BAD CODE: do not steal. Fixed version below.
}  // setEngine

- (void)dealloc{
  [engine release]; // Retaining count is reducing
  [super dealloc];
}    


some_function 
{
   Engine *engine = [Engine new]; // count: 1

   Car *car1 = [Car new]; // +1 for car1
   Car *car2 = [Car new]; // +1 for car2

   [car1 setEngine: engine];   // count: 2 But why? 1-1=0 (due to [engine release]  
                              // in -(void) SetEngine.    
                              // and after engine=[newEngine retain] retain count is 1.

   [engine release]; // count 1 
   [car2 setEngine: [car1 engine]]; // count 2 - Here Car2 retaining same 
                                    //engine retained by Car1. So retain 
                                    //count of engine increases.

   [car1 release];// count 1
   [car2 release];// count 0


   return 0;
}
```